# Abandon Spring Batch Partitioned Jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

When running a partitioned step in Spring Batch, if you stop then the partitioned steps will step eventually. Then if you abandon the job while the steps are still stopping spring batch appears to become confused. It appears that the stopping of the partitioned steps no longer send messages back to the parent step and the parent step listener either keeps listening or somehow gets orphaned.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Making any changes to the job repository while the job/step is in one of the *ING states is a bad idea.  Is there a reason you can't wait to abandon the job until the slaves stop?

Comment: We are using the Spring Batch Admin UI. When you press STOP, the screen refreshes and shows ABANDON button. It gives the impression that you can press and clean up faster. The ABANDON button is only visible while in STOPPING state.